# Difference Between MySql <> NULL and IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my db there is a varchar(255) column and for some records it contains null values,
when i fired this

```
SELECT * FORM my_table where some_column <> NULL;
```

nothing is returned

but when is fired

```
SELECT * FORM my_table where some_column IS NOT NULL;
```

I got desired records

can you explain what's the main difference between them and when to use <> and != operators.

Comment: The second is the correct, documented, and standard way to compare a value to `NULL` in SQL.  For all practical purposes, the first is a typo.

Comment: `NULL <> NULL` is `NULL`, not true. Comparing `NULL` to any other value including `NULL` is always `NULL` and therefore not true, regardless of the comparison operator, unless it is `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Additional detail: `some_column = NULL` always returns false. Also `some_column <> NULL` always returns false.

Comment: @RobertKock - no it doesn't - it returns `UNKNOWN`/`NULL`. If your assertion was correct `NOT (some_column = NULL)` would be true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't know that. Forget my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the Mysql 8 Reference:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to
>   test for NULL. Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with
>   NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such
>   comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

In mysql  a string column can be  empty  = '' or NUL  (not  values assigned )

so  you should use  for not empty

```
  SELECT * FORM my_table where some_column <> '';
```

or

```
  SELECT * FORM my_table where some_column  != '';
```

or  not equal to a value

```
  SELECT * FORM my_table where some_column <> 'my_value';
  SELECT * FORM my_table where some_column != 'my_value';
```

for not null  you must use the special operator IS NOT NULL

```
SELECT * FORM my_table where some_column IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: so when to use <> and != operators ?

Comment: You need  <> or !=  when you want check if the string is different from a string value  see .. updated ..answer